# Html.DisplayNameFor() relation through entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looping through each item in a model, and I display the name and data for several of the properties. This works fine.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <div class="Ticket">
    <h3>
    @item.Title
    </h3>

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
```

Since the model has an associated DataAnnotation which provide formatting clues, this ends up outputting someting like "Created 1/1/1". Good so far.

What I'd also like to do is display the [formatted] name for an item that is associated with the model through the entity framework. I can display the data parameter using the code...

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LinkedEntity.Data)
```

but I'm unable to figure out the syntax to display the associated label. Any ideas?